Analyzing shear stress of plate
I would like to conduct a nonlinear analysis to obtain the stress-strain curve of a plate subjected to shear force, as depicted in the figure below. However, I am encountering difficulties in setting up the boundary conditions to ensure that the four edges of the plate maintain linear behavior. I would appreciate advice on setting appropriate boundary conditions, assuming simply supported conditions.

I'm using Ansys APDl program.

If you embed the plate in a larger plate subjected to shear loading (of whatever type), Saint-Venant's principle ensures that the stress in the original plate, far from the edges of the larger plate, will be closer to a state of pure shear.
